# Probabilistic models problem

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Problem:
The probability of a player making a free throw is 0.6. Find the probability that the player makes the first at least 7 consecutive free throws.

The problem is that I have a dilemma: the requirement sounds for me that I need to use the formula from Poisson Model, but in that case, number of successes will be 8 (because "at least 7"), and I don't know how to find the number of trials, it will be also 8? Is it correct what I suppose?

Comment: Why Poisson?  the probability of making $n$ in a row is just $.6^n$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's worth noting:

- "at least $7$" means $\geq 7$
- "more than $7$" means $> 7$

---

In your problem, the probability that the player makes all $7$ consecutive free throws is simply $$0.6^7\,=\, 0.0279936$$

Whether or not they make any shots after the $7^\text{th}$ is irrelevant.

Comment: That was my mistake :). Thanks a lot!